# DEX/UCS - G85 - Record Integrity Check

Tags: crc16

I need to write a C procedure to calculate the CRC16 (G85 - Record Integrity Check) for a DEX/UCS transaction. Searching the internet, I could not find a complete, fully described algorithm anywhere.
I also read the "DEX/UCS Programmer`s Guide" without finding anything of interest.

Comment: "It is calculated by using the CRC algorithm in the _UCS for DSD Implementors and User Guide_, which may be obtained from the GS1-US organization." You need to get that document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This [code found here](https://github.com/walmartlabs/gozer/pull/19/commits/72a8ffbd229a5ef4b70ebcb045a77f673b49ed4a) says that it calculates the mentioned CRC:

```java
public class Crc16 implements CyclicRedundancyCheck {

    public static final int[] table = { 0x0000, 0xC0C1, 0xC181, 0x0140, 0xC301, 0x03C0, 0x0280, 0xC241, 0xC601, 0x06C0, 0x0780, 0xC741, 0x0500,
            0xC5C1, 0xC481, 0x0440, 0xCC01, 0x0CC0, 0x0D80, 0xCD41, 0x0F00, 0xCFC1, 0xCE81, 0x0E40, 0x0A00, 0xCAC1, 0xCB81, 0x0B40, 0xC901, 0x09C0,
            0x0880, 0xC841, 0xD801, 0x18C0, 0x1980, 0xD941, 0x1B00, 0xDBC1, 0xDA81, 0x1A40, 0x1E00, 0xDEC1, 0xDF81, 0x1F40, 0xDD01, 0x1DC0, 0x1C80,
            0xDC41, 0x1400, 0xD4C1, 0xD581, 0x1540, 0xD701, 0x17C0, 0x1680, 0xD641, 0xD201, 0x12C0, 0x1380, 0xD341, 0x1100, 0xD1C1, 0xD081, 0x1040,
            0xF001, 0x30C0, 0x3180, 0xF141, 0x3300, 0xF3C1, 0xF281, 0x3240, 0x3600, 0xF6C1, 0xF781, 0x3740, 0xF501, 0x35C0, 0x3480, 0xF441, 0x3C00,
            0xFCC1, 0xFD81, 0x3D40, 0xFF01, 0x3FC0, 0x3E80, 0xFE41, 0xFA01, 0x3AC0, 0x3B80, 0xFB41, 0x3900, 0xF9C1, 0xF881, 0x3840, 0x2800, 0xE8C1,
            0xE981, 0x2940, 0xEB01, 0x2BC0, 0x2A80, 0xEA41, 0xEE01, 0x2EC0, 0x2F80, 0xEF41, 0x2D00, 0xEDC1, 0xEC81, 0x2C40, 0xE401, 0x24C0, 0x2580,
            0xE541, 0x2700, 0xE7C1, 0xE681, 0x2640, 0x2200, 0xE2C1, 0xE381, 0x2340, 0xE101, 0x21C0, 0x2080, 0xE041, 0xA001, 0x60C0, 0x6180, 0xA141,
            0x6300, 0xA3C1, 0xA281, 0x6240, 0x6600, 0xA6C1, 0xA781, 0x6740, 0xA501, 0x65C0, 0x6480, 0xA441, 0x6C00, 0xACC1, 0xAD81, 0x6D40, 0xAF01,
            0x6FC0, 0x6E80, 0xAE41, 0xAA01, 0x6AC0, 0x6B80, 0xAB41, 0x6900, 0xA9C1, 0xA881, 0x6840, 0x7800, 0xB8C1, 0xB981, 0x7940, 0xBB01, 0x7BC0,
            0x7A80, 0xBA41, 0xBE01, 0x7EC0, 0x7F80, 0xBF41, 0x7D00, 0xBDC1, 0xBC81, 0x7C40, 0xB401, 0x74C0, 0x7580, 0xB541, 0x7700, 0xB7C1, 0xB681,
            0x7640, 0x7200, 0xB2C1, 0xB381, 0x7340, 0xB101, 0x71C0, 0x7080, 0xB041, 0x5000, 0x90C1, 0x9181, 0x5140, 0x9301, 0x53C0, 0x5280, 0x9241,
            0x9601, 0x56C0, 0x5780, 0x9741, 0x5500, 0x95C1, 0x9481, 0x5440, 0x9C01, 0x5CC0, 0x5D80, 0x9D41, 0x5F00, 0x9FC1, 0x9E81, 0x5E40, 0x5A00,
            0x9AC1, 0x9B81, 0x5B40, 0x9901, 0x59C0, 0x5880, 0x9841, 0x8801, 0x48C0, 0x4980, 0x8941, 0x4B00, 0x8BC1, 0x8A81, 0x4A40, 0x4E00, 0x8EC1,
            0x8F81, 0x4F40, 0x8D01, 0x4DC0, 0x4C80, 0x8C41, 0x4400, 0x84C1, 0x8581, 0x4540, 0x8701, 0x47C0, 0x4680, 0x8641, 0x8201, 0x42C0, 0x4380,
            0x8341, 0x4100, 0x81C1, 0x8081, 0x4040, };

    @Override
    public String generateCyclicRedundancyCheck(String blockOfText) {
        String hexString = null;

        if (blockOfText != null && blockOfText.length() > 0) {
            byte[] bytes = blockOfText.getBytes();
            int crc = 0x0000;

            for (byte b : bytes) {
                crc = (crc >>> 8) ^ table[(crc ^ b) & 0xff];
            }

            hexString = Integer.toHexString(crc).toUpperCase();
        }

        return hexString;
    }
```